# Do the TO_DATE function in Oracle 11g PL/SQL have upper/lower limits

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle development and am still discovering a lot of it's capabilities and the differences between PL/SQL and SQL Server's T-SQL.

So my 'project' is to create a function that would generate a random date from either the future or the past. The user should be able to specify the upper/lower bounds in which the date should be created.

I may be too late but in the interest of breivity I will skip the details of why the function does what it does and how. What is important and pertinent to the actual questions is the following behavoir.

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 6469), 'yyyy/mm/dd')); -- Dec 31, 2031
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE - 4853), 'yyyy/mm/dd'));  -- Jan 01, 2001
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 7000), 'yyyy/mm/dd'));  -- ERROR
END
```

Simply put, when I add enough days to the SYSTEM date to exceed Dec 31, 2031 I get the following error message ... *"a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"*  ... . I experience the same problem when I subtract enough days from the SYSTEM date to pre-date Jan 01, 2001.

When I remove the format it's doesn't break but returns an impossible date ...

```
BEGIN
    -- returns 15-JUN-33  
    -- June 33rd 2015!!
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 7000))); 
END
```

So it appears to me that there is some sort of date range limit on this function ... JAN 01, 2001 - DEC 31, 2031 ... Is that true or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Forget all those functions for a second.  You are making mistakes that may be skewing your results.  Instead, try this:  to_char(sysdate + 7000, 'yyyy/mm/dd').  As far as what you are doing wrong, read the docs on to_date and trunc.  Pay attention to the data types they return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work through the data types here.

`sysdate` returns a `date`.  Adding a `number` to a `date` returns a `date` that many days in the future.  So, for example, `sysdate + 7000` is June 15, 2033.  `trunc(sysdate + 7000)` also returns a date, it just sets the time to midnight.  So far, so good.

The problem comes when you take that `date` and pass it to the `to_date` function.  Logically, that doesn't make sense.  You already have a `date`, there is no need to convert it to a `date`.  Practically, `to_date` does not accept a `date` as a parameter.  It only accepts a string.  Now, Oracle can implicitly convert the `date` you have to a string using your session's `nls_date_format` setting which is what it does here.  Best case, you're taking a `date`, implicitly converting that to a string, then explicitly converting that string back to exactly the same `date` that you started with.  If your session's `nls_date_format` happens not to match the format mask that you're providing to the `to_date`, however, you'll likely get an error which is what you're seeing here.

Walking through an example, let's use the date of midnight on June 15, 2033.  If you call `to_date` on that, Oracle has to convert the date to a string using your session's `nls_date_format`.  If you're in the United States and you haven't changed anything about your client, your `nls_date_format` is probably `DD-MON-RR`.  That means that your date gets converted to the string `15-JUN-33` when it is passed in to `to_date`.  So, logically, you're trying to do something like

```
dbms_output.put_line( to_date( '15-JUN-33', 'yyyy/mm/dd' ));
```

When you look at it this way, it's obvious that the format mask doesn't match the format of the string which causes an error.  If your `nls_date_format` is closer to the format mask in your `to_date`, it is possible that the `to_date` call will run successfully but return a different date than you expect (switching the month and the day for example).

The simple answer is that you should never call `to_date` on a day.  You should only call `to_date` on a string.  If you want to convert a `date` into a string in a particular format for display, use `to_char` not `to_date`.

Going back to the original question, yes there are limits to what constitutes a valid date in Oracle.  A valid `date` must be between Jan 1, 4712 BC (6700 years ago) to Dec 31, 9999 (7900 years from now).  It doesn't appear that you are anywhere near exceeding those limits.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I was modeling off an example I saw somewhere else and incorrectly assumed that what they had done must have been correct.

Comment: Nice explanation @Justin Cave